# Opentelemetry data to Elastic APM. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Required SETTINGS preface not received

Tags: java, elasticsearch, open-telemetry, elastic-apm, otlp-grpc

I am trying to instrument my spring boot app with opentelemetry and send the telemetry data such as logs, metrics, traces to Elastic APM.
Added otel agent v1.18.0 to classpath.
Elastic APM and apps are running on k8s.
I have followed the docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/open-telemetry.html

```
exec java -XX:MinRAMPercentage=70 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70 --add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/app/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar -Dotel.service.name=sync-data -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://ip:8200 -Delastic.apm.verify_server_cert=false '-Dotel.exporter.otlp.headers=Authorization=Bearer secret_token' -jar sync-data.jar

INFO io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.VersionLogger - opentelemetry-javaagent - version: 1.18.0
[OkHttp http://ip:8200/...] ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export metrics. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Canceled
[otel.javaagent 2022-10-09 12:54:48:576 +0000] [OkHttp http://ip:8200/...] ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export metrics. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Required SETTINGS preface not received
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration details and how to replicate, or give the full log details.

Comment: I suspect it will be connectivity. Check ports and that the exporting app can reach the elastic APM.